# Rails 3 ActiveRecord query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Given a Rails 3 app with the following models:

```rb
# == Schema Information
# Schema version: 20110517144920
#
# Table name: orders
#
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  user_id    :integer         not null
#  name       :string(255)     not null
#  state      :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
#

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to                          :user
  has_many                            :multipage_pdfs,  :as => :assetable,   :dependent => :destroy
  has_many                            :singlepage_pdfs, :as => :assetable,   :dependent => :destroy
  ...
end


# == Schema Information
# Schema version: 20110511064747
#
# Table name: assets
#
#  id             :integer         not null, primary key
#  assetable_id   :integer         not null
#  assetable_type :string(255)     not null
#  state          :string(255)
#  type           :string(255)     not null
#  name           :string(255)     not null
#  document       :string(255)     not null
#  version        :integer         default(0), not null
#  created_at     :datetime
#  updated_at     :datetime
#

class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end


class SinglepagePdf < Asset
  ...
end
```

asset#version is increased each time a new asset is created, if an asset with an identical name exists, so that's what my assets typically look like (simplified):

```
    | id | assetable_id | assetable_type  |   name  | version | type           |
    |  1 |             1 |           Order | my.pdf  |        1 | SinglepagePdf |
    |  2 |             1 |           Order | my.pdf  |        2 | SinglepagePdf |
    |  3 |             1 |           Order | my.pdf  |        3 | SinglepagePdf |
    |  4 |             1 |           Order | bla.pdf |        1 | SinglepagePdf |
```

Now i need to get all singlepage_pdfs of a single order, but only the last version for each name. How can i achieve this?

```rb
o = Order.find(1)
singlepage_pdfs = o.singlepage_pdfs.find(...)
```

The result should contain only contain the Assets with id 3 and 4...

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it groups all singlepage_pdfs by name and returns the latest version of each

```
o.singlepage_pdfs.group("name").order("version DESC")
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwer. I'm getting this error: `Column 'asset_id' must be present within GROUP_BY Clause`. Maybe worth mentioning i'm using PostgreSQL...

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**, I'm not sure your associations are set up correctly. You may need to introduce another layer so you have something like:

```
Order has_many Asset belongs_to Assetable(polymorphic)
```

Then you can define scoped associations for each assetable type in the `Order` model (via `has_many :through`).

**Secondly**, in terms of the way you are doing versioning, I would highly recommend doing it differently and using an established mechanism to do so. Example libraries to handle this for you:

- [version_fu](https://github.com/jmckible/version_fu) (recommended)
- [acts_as_versioned](https://github.com/technoweenie/acts_as_versioned)
- [paper_trail](http://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) (more advanced)